# Bulk insertion in hibernate implemented but records inserted row by row as seen in logs

Tags: hibernate, bulkinsert

Trying to bulk insert into a table using API:
Using hibernate for the same,since I am flushing the session after every 100  records,a batch insert query of 100 records is expected to be executed,but the logs show individual query for each row.Is there some other way to implement batch insert in hibernate?

```
public void bulkInsert(List<PlatinumUserInfo> ptInfo) 
    {
        try
        {

        Session session=hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        int count=1;
        for(PlatinumUserInfo record:ptInfo)
        {
            try
            {
            if(count % 100 == 0) { 
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
                tx.commit();
                tx=session.beginTransaction();
            }
            session.save(record);
            count++;
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.info("rolling back txn !");
            session.clear();
            tx.rollback();
            tx=session.beginTransaction();
        }
        }   
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.info("exception occurred while bulk insertion !"+e);

        }

    }
```

Logs:

Hibernate: insert into yt_platinum_user (id_platinum_user, email, first_name, insert_date, is_fresco_updated, is_infinity_updated, is_mo_updated, last_name, link_rewrite, phone, title, update_date) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into yt_platinum_user (id_platinum_user, email, first_name, insert_date, is_fresco_updated, is_infinity_updated, is_mo_updated, last_name, link_rewrite, phone, title, update_date) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into yt_platinum_user (id_platinum_user, email, first_name, insert_date, is_fresco_updated, is_infinity_updated, is_mo_updated, last_name, link_rewrite, phone, title, update_date) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use batch procesing then you need to enable JDBC batch processing:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
```

Comment: I ve enabled it   :                                                                                             <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>